# incrementing a field in firestore (php)

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a way to increment a field in firestore like in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters?origin_team=T03KMNH3F).

```
shard_ref.update("count", firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1));
```

The only caveat is that I am trying to use [firestore Client Sdk](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore) or the [Admin Sdk](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for php.

What is a clean solution for incrementing a field in php. Does it require both read and write operations or is it possible with only write operation?

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore/blob/master/src/FieldValue.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Firestore Client Sdk](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore) has the ability to increment a field. (use negative values to decrement).
You can use it in the following way to update the field with $field_name:

```
$data = [
            [
                   'path' => $field_name,
                   'value' => \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment($increment_value);
            ]
        ];     
$doc_ref->update($data);
```

If you are using a batching you call it as follows

```
$data[$field_name] = \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment($increment_value);
$batch->add_to_batch('update', $doc_ref, $data);
```

Here is additional [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore/blob/master/src/FieldValue.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you have more data you can do

```
$data = [
'name' => $name,
 'email' => $email,
 'likes'=> \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue::increment(1) // Add + 1
      ] ;
```